# How to make my react-multi-carousel use a light-box feature for my ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-multi-carousel

I have images coming in from a rest api, into my application. Those images then get populated into a **react-multi-carousel**. What I would like to do is to make those images clickable for a light-box. I am fairly new to React. My code for the carousel slider so far is:

**slider.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import '../slider/slider.css';
  import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
  import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

  const responsive = {
      superLargeDesktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
          items: 1,
      },
      desktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
          items: 1,
      },
      tablet: {
          breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
          items: 1,
      },
      mobile: {
          breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
          items: 1,
      },
  };

  class Slider extends Component {
      _isMounted = false;

      state = {
          awsApiData: [],
          loading: false,
      }

      componentDidMount() {
          this._isMounted = true;
          console.log('app mounted');
          this.setState({ loading: true });
          /*global fetch */
          fetch('https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx')
              .then(data => data.json())
              .then(data => this.setState({ awsApiData: data[0], loading: false }, () => console.log(data)));
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
          this._isMounted = false;
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <div>
              {this.state.loading
                    ? <div className="text-center">Loading...</div>
                    : 
                        <Carousel
                            additionalTransfrom={0}
                            showDots={false}
                            arrows={true}
                            autoPlaySpeed={3000}
                            autoPlay={false}
                            centerMode={false}
                            className="slider"
                            containerClass="container-with-dots"
                            dotListClass="dots"
                            draggable
                            focusOnSelect={false}
                            infinite
                            itemClass="carousel-top"
                            keyBoardControl
                            minimumTouchDrag={80}
                            renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
                            renderDotsOutside
                            responsive={responsive}>
                           {Object.values(this.state.awsApiData).map((post, indx) => {
  return (
      <div className="mt-5" key={indx}>
          <img className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero" src={post.image} alt="Alt text"></img>

      </div>
  );
})}
                        </Carousel>
              }
                        </div>
          );
      }
  }

  export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the lightbox by hand by issuing an `onClick` for each image and enlarging the image, adding captions, full screen etc.

It is a lot easier if you can make use of existing libraries to implement lightbox feature for your carousal such as [react-images](http://jossmac.github.io/react-images/#/).

Here is the working copy of your code with light box feature implemented(using react-multi-carousel and react-images).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-corousal-issue-72s9o?file=/src/Slider.js

Here is the code snippet.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import "../slider/slider.css";
import "./slider.css";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
import LightBox, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";

const responsive = {
  superLargeDesktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
    items: 1
  },
  desktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
    items: 1
  },
  tablet: {
    breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
    items: 1
  },
  mobile: {
    breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
    items: 1
  }
};

class Slider extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  state = {
    awsApiData: [],
    loading: false,
    selectedIndex: 0,
    lightboxIsOpen: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    console.log("app mounted");
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    /*global fetch */
    // fetch("https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxx")
    fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=10")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data =>
        // this.setState({ awsApiData: data[0], loading: false }, () =>
        this.setState(
          {
            awsApiData: data.map(item => ({ source: item.download_url })),
            loading: false
          },
          () => console.log(data)
        )
      );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  toggleLightbox = selectedIndex => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      lightboxIsOpen: !state.lightboxIsOpen,
      selectedIndex
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <div className="text-center">Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Carousel
              additionalTransfrom={0}
              showDots={false}
              arrows={true}
              autoPlaySpeed={3000}
              autoPlay={true}
              centerMode={false}
              className="slider"
              containerClass="container-with-dots"
              dotListClass="dots"
              draggable
              focusOnSelect={false}
              infinite
              itemClass="carousel-top"
              keyBoardControl
              minimumTouchDrag={80}
              renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
              renderDotsOutside
              responsive={responsive}
            >
              {Object.values(this.state.awsApiData).map((post, indx) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    className="mt-5"
                    key={indx}
                    onClick={() => this.toggleLightbox(indx)}
                  >
                    <img
                      className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero"
                      src={post.source}
                      alt="Alt text"
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </Carousel>
            <ModalGateway>
              {this.state.lightboxIsOpen ? (
                <Modal onClose={this.toggleLightbox}>
                  <LightBox
                    components={{
                      FooterCaption: () => <div>footer caption</div>
                    }}
                    currentIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                    // formatters={{ getAltText }}
                    frameProps={{ autoSize: "height" }}
                    views={this.state.awsApiData}
                  />
                </Modal>
              ) : null}
            </ModalGateway>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it needed some tweaks from me but worked fine.

Comment: One question I have is - you have mapped the download_url for the image for this, but what if I wanted to display the Author in the footer caption for instance based on your api example? How could this be achieved as you are only calling in the download_Url?

Comment: in that case maintain all required info(author, imageUrl etc) in the state .. in your case `awsApiData` ... I have updated the code in the sandbox to display author in the footer caption... i have commented the old code purposefully so you can see the difference... reload your code sandbox browser ... enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, I think there is an issue though as the Author name is always the same, so it doesn't seem to be getting from the Indx?

Comment: i see - should be simple fix.. i will take a look at it a bit later..and let you know..

Comment: yes - do this `<div>shot by - {props.currentView.author}</div> ` to display the author properly ... i have updated the codesandbox as well.. thx..