# React images caption error from api maybe to do with correct Index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image, react-multi-carousel

Following on from: [How to make my react-multi-carousel use a light-box feature for my ReactJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219761/how-to-make-my-react-multi-carousel-use-a-light-box-feature-for-my-reactjs-app/61221279?noredirect=1#comment108339847_61221279)

My app is using react-images for lightbox and react-carousel-images for the carousel. My api has a title and image. Problem I have is the title in the footer caption is always coming as the image selected and not changing when in the lightbox carousel. I think it is to do with the index of the selected image? My code so far is:

example of issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-corousal-issue-72s9o?file=/src/Slider.js

**slider.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import "../slider/slider.css";
import "./slider.css";
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";
import LightBox, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";

const responsive = {
  superLargeDesktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
    items: 1
  },
  desktop: {
    breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
    items: 1
  },
  tablet: {
    breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
    items: 1
  },
  mobile: {
    breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
    items: 1
  }
};

class Slider extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  state = {
    awsApiData: [],
    loading: false,
    //selectedIndex: 0,
    selectedImage: {},
    lightboxIsOpen: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    console.log("app mounted");
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    /*global fetch */
    fetch("https://onelbip0e6.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/livestage/imgApi")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data =>
        // this.setState({ awsApiData: data[0], loading: false }, () =>
        this.setState(
          {
            // awsApiData: data.map(item => ({source: item.download_url })),
            awsApiData: data.map(item => ({
              ...item,
              source: item.image
            })),
            loading: false
          },
          () => console.log(data)
        )
      );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  toggleLightbox = (post, selectedIndex) => {
    // this.setState(state => ({
    //   lightboxIsOpen: !state.lightboxIsOpen,
    //   selectedIndex
    // }));
    this.setState(state => ({
      lightboxIsOpen: !state.lightboxIsOpen,
      selectedImage: { title: post.title, index: selectedIndex }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <div className="text-center">Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Carousel
              additionalTransfrom={0}
              showDots={false}
              arrows={true}
              autoPlaySpeed={3000}
              autoPlay={true}
              centerMode={false}
              className="slider"
              containerClass="container-with-dots"
              dotListClass="dots"
              draggable
              focusOnSelect={false}
              infinite
              itemClass="carousel-top"
              keyBoardControl
              minimumTouchDrag={80}
              renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
              renderDotsOutside
              responsive={responsive}
            >
              {Object.values(this.state.awsApiData).map((post, indx) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    className="mt-5"
                    key={indx}
                    //onClick={() => this.toggleLightbox(indx)}
                    onClick={() => this.toggleLightbox(post, indx)}

                  >
                    <img
                      className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero"
                      src={post.source}
                      alt="Alt text"
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </Carousel>
            <ModalGateway>
              {this.state.lightboxIsOpen ? (
                <Modal onClose={this.toggleLightbox}>
                  <LightBox
                    components={{
                      FooterCaption: () => <div>{this.state.selectedImage.title}</div>
                    }}
                    //currentIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                   currentIndex={this.state.selectedImage.index}
                    // formatters={{ getAltText }}
                    frameProps={{ autoSize: "height" }}
                    views={this.state.awsApiData}
                  />
                </Modal>
              ) : null}
            </ModalGateway>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your caption is set to `this.state.selectedImage.title` but you never update the state (i.e. call `setState()`) when your light box view changes.

You need to add the `onViewChange` handler to the `LightBox` component:

```
<LightBox onViewChange={handleLightBoxViewChange} .../>
```

That handler will receive the index of the item the view changes too. In `handleLightBoxViewChange` call `setState` to update `selectedImage`:

```
handleLightBoxViewChange = (newIndex) => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    selectedImage: state.awsApiData[newIndex]
  }));
};
```

If you don't wish to update the state, your footer component receives the current view so you could update it like this:

```
<LightBox
  components={{
    FooterCaption: ({currentView}) => <div>{currentView.title}</div>
  }}
  //...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks either of those options worked. Is there a preferred way to do this i.e update state or just do it via the view?

Comment: @Sole I don't think there is a preferred way, you just need to decide which suits your needs the best. Updating the `FooterCaption` is the simplest, which is generally a good way to go.